# Grails 3 influence column encoding in MySQL

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-3.0

In order to be able to store emoji in MySql, I'd like to change one column encoding to utf8mb4. The rest should stay in utf8.

I can do this in production as I'm using database migration:

```
ALTER TABLE message CHANGE content content TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But is there any way how to do it for development environment? The only way what I found is to run sql in bootstrap: [Executing SQL inserts during Grails application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452933/executing-sql-inserts-during-grails-application-startup)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: ha ha, I think there is no better solution tan pure groovy sql...

Comment: Dev didn't matter so much for me. Test and Prod, I ended up altering the DB column on the server since I have the schema set to 'update'.